# Find basis $v_1,...,v_m$ with desired properties.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

- $w_1,...,w_n$ is a basis $W$
- $V$ is finite-dimensional
- $T \in L(V,W)$

Prove from this that there exists a basis $v_1,...,v_m$ of $V$ such that all the entries of the first row equal $0$ except for possibly the entry in the first column of the matrix $M(T, (v_1,...,v_m),(w_1,...,w_n)$.

I am struggling a bit with this one, I thought I had a solution, but it turned out to be based on a false assumption.

FYI, this is exercise 3C.5 from LADR by Axler.

Comment: What is the matrix $M(T,(v_1,\dots,v_m),(w_1,\dots,w_n))$?

Comment: It is the matrix of the linear transformation $T \in L(V,W)$.

Comment: @Labbsserts Your answer here is not specific enough. *The* matrix depends on a basis for $V$ and a basis for $W$. If you change bases, the matrix changes drastically.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't quite follow, how have I changed bases? What I am trying to ask is to find a basis $v_1,...,v_m$ of $V$ such that the matrix $M(T)$ holds the desired properties.

Comment: Had forgotten that $v_1,..., v_m$ is supposed to be a basis for $V$, but that is edited now. I hope my question is understandable now.

Comment: I was just saying that your answer to William's notation question was not proper.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. @William sorry if my answer was ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1: For two different choices of bases of $V$, the corresponding matrices $M$ and $\tilde{M}$ are related by $M = \tilde{M} B$ for some invertible change-of-basis matrix $B$. The question now is, if $\tilde{M}$ is the matrix with respect to some arbitrary basis of $V$, can we come up with some $B$ such that $M=\tilde{M}B$ becomes of the form stated in the question? Note that multiplication by $B$ on the right can encode elementary column operations on $\tilde{M}$ (similar to [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Elementary_row_operations)). If you can convince yourself that applying column operations can transform $\tilde{M}$ into a matrix $M$ of the desired form (think about a "column version" of Gaussian elimination), then this essentially completes the proof.

---

Approach 2: If $w_1$ is not in the image of $T$, then any basis will do. So, WLOG assume $w_1$ is in the image of $T$. Let $v_1$ be such that $T(v_1)=w_1$. Iteratively extend this to a basis by performing the following for $i=2,3,\ldots,m$.

- Find some $\tilde{v}_i$ such that $\{v_1,\ldots, v_{i-1}, \tilde{v}_i\}$ is linearly independent.
- $T \tilde{v}_i = c_1 w_1 + \cdots + c_n w_n$ for some $c_1,\ldots, c_n$.
- Let $v_i = \tilde{v}_i - c_1 v_1$ and note that $T v_i = c_2 w_2 + \cdots + c_n w_n$.
- Check that $\{v_1,\ldots, v_{i-1}, {v}_i\}$ is still linearly independent.

Check that this choice of basis has a matrix satisfying the desired conditions.